# Take in multiple key presses javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keypress

I am making a pong game, in which one paddle is controlled by the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>, and the other by <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd>. I have the code working for both to move using the keys, but if one person is holding down <kbd>↓</kbd> to move their paddle down, and the other person presses <kbd>w</kbd>, then only the 2<sup>nd</sup> person's paddle will start to move. Is there any way to fix this?

Relevant code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
        var key = e.which;
        if(key == "38") d = "up";
        else if(key == "40") d = "down";
        if(key == "87") t = "up";
        else if(key == "83") t = "down";
})
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QYKH/48/)

Comment: Listen to key down and up events and remember which keys are pressed across events.

Comment: @plalx thanks! The duplicate question helped a lot :)